# Can't hide Displayform ribbon,using CEWP or CSS in 2010

Tags: 2010, ribbon, display-form, cewp

I have been trying to hide the Manage and Actions ribbon on DisplayForm.aspx, using a browser inserted CEWP and just entering:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #s4-ribbonrow {display:none}
</style>
```

through the browser.

I have also tried entering it in the code, through SPD2010, but neither does the job.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, as it seems to work for others on the forum?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `! important` to force applying this style as the following :

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-ribbonrow { display: none !important; }
</style>
```

For more details check [How to hide Ribbon in SharePoint 2010 using CSS](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/27/how-to-hide-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-using-css/)